# using CompletionStage instead of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, lambda, completable-future, completion-stage

given the following method:

```
private static String getChuckNorrisJoke () {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new
        URL( "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random" ).openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Something is wrong: " , e);
    }
}
```

the following statement can be used to run the method in an asynchronous fashion.

```
final CompletableFuture<String> jokeAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getChuckNorrisJoke());
```

although I think that I understand `CompletionStage` relation to `CompletableFuture`, I am not sure how I can use `CompletionStage` to accomplish same task.

```
final CompletionStage<String> jokeAsync = ?
```

also, I am not sure about "combining stages"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CompletionStage` is the interface implemented by `CompletableFuture`, so you can just declare `jokeAsync` as a `CompletionStage` and it will work:

```
final CompletionStage<String> jokeAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getChuckNorrisJoke());
```

If you have several stages, you can combine them in different ways, like:

- [`thenCombine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to combine the result of 2 stages
- [`applyToEither()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#applyToEither-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.Function-) to process the result of the first one that completes and return a new stage with the result
- [`acceptEither()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#acceptEither-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.Consumer-) to consume the result of either without returning a new result
- [`runAfterBoth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#runAfterBoth-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.lang.Runnable-) and [`runAfterEither()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#runAfterEither-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.lang.Runnable-) to run an operation after both or either stage is completed.

The `CompletionStage` API does not offer some operations that are only provided by `CompletableFuture`:

- submitting tasks, e.g. with `supplyAsync()`
- combining many stages with `allOf()` and `anyOf()`
- programmatically completing stages or creating already completed stages
- waiting for a stage's result with `join()` or `get()`

But the [`toCompletableFuture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#toCompletableFuture--) allows to convert any stage and thus bridge the gap.

Comment: like this?

    final CompletionStage<String> firstJokeAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getChuckNorrisJoke());
    final CompletionStage<String> secondJokeAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getChuckNorrisJoke());
    return firstJokeAsync.thenCombineAsync(secondJokeAsync, service);

Comment: If `service` is a `BiFunction` that accepts 2 `String` parameters and returns some result, then yes.

Comment: BiFunction<String, String,String> service = (x, y) -> {return x + y; };..... yes, this works fine. it concatenates the 2 Strings together. but is there a nice way to get the output of (.thenCombineAsync) to match this type (CompletionStage<List<String>>)

Comment: Just make a list out of it: `BiFunction<String, String, List<String>> service = (x, y) -> Arrays.asList(x, y);`